# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (270): x, y, colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the results of the multiple regression model of the data below

```
  spp.nms[, 2]   variable       value
 1   -0.28547969       Plot  1.00000000
 2    0.34730550       Plot  2.00000000
 3    0.05984583       Plot  3.00000000
 4    0.20147975       Plot  4.00000000
 5    0.31828558       Plot  5.00000000
 6   -0.28547969        Log  1.00000000
 7    0.34730550        Log  1.00000000
 8    0.05984583        Log  1.00000000
 9    0.20147975        Log  1.00000000
10    0.31828558        Log  1.00000000
11    0.24869223        Log  0.00000000
12   -0.35147868        Log  0.00000000
13   -0.44278265        Log  0.00000000
14   -0.28047515        Log  0.00000000
15    0.32283950        Log  0.00000000
16   -0.28547969      Soil1 -7.43637019
17    0.34730550      Soil1 -2.55011049
18    0.05984583      Soil1 -4.70072757
19    0.20147975      Soil1  1.04846090
20    0.31828558      Soil1  0.60488995
21   -0.50656941      Soil2  1.15166319
22    0.11406246      Soil2  1.29153863
23    0.24252115      Soil2 -1.24299685
24    0.39305738      Soil2 -0.71739651
25    0.49439872      Soil2          NA
26   -0.50656941      Soil3 -2.04573421
27    0.11406246      Soil3 -1.22057237
28    0.24252115      Soil3  0.09168261
29    0.39305738      Soil3  1.14051538
30    0.49439872      Soil3          NA
31   -0.28547969  Disttovil  3.89100000
32    0.34730550  Disttovil  7.20900000
33    0.05984583  Disttovil  7.57900000
34    0.20147975  Disttovil 12.25300000
35    0.31828558  Disttovil 15.39600000
36   -0.28547969 Disttostrm  1.82658621
37    0.34730550 Disttostrm  0.95400297
38    0.05984583 Disttostrm  2.27278375
39    0.20147975 Disttostrm  1.86702254
40    0.31828558 Disttostrm  2.23311494
41   -0.28547969        LAI  4.31000000
42    0.34730550        LAI  3.49000000
43    0.05984583        LAI  2.60000000
44    0.20147975        LAI  3.98000000
45    0.31828558        LAI  3.66000000
```

This is the script that I have written to obtain the plots of all the regressions

```
require(reshape2)
data_trial<-melt(data_nms2, id.vars = "spp.nms[, 2]")

ggplot(data_trial) +
  geom_point(aes(value,spp.nms[, 2], color=variable)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(value,spp.nms[, 2], colour=variable), 
              method=lm, se=FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_x") +
  labs(x = "Variables", 
       y = "Species Composition along NMS axis2")
```

But I get this error

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data : x, y, colour

Comment: Wow, your column is actually named `"spp.nms[, 2]"`?! Try using a sensible column name first and see what happens. Odds are that will help.

Comment: @joran It now says - Error: Unknown parameters: method, se

Comment: Yeah, `method` and `se` are not valid arguments to `geom_jitter`. Honestly not sure where you got that from at all. Those are things you'd specify in, say, `geom_smooth`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that link. It demonstrates exactly what I wrote in my comment.

Comment: Ooo right. Thanks  a lot!